# Axis2 Migration

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, phase

We had an application using axis2 1.0. We recently migrated to axis2 1.4. After migration we  are facing the following error at runtime:

```
public static org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromURIs(java.net.URL,java.net.URL) throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault] threw exception; 
nested exception is org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid phases please recheck axis2.xml {0} for the handler {1}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.wellpoint.integration.saf.api.SAFServiceFactory.<init>(SAFServiceFactory.java:45)
    at com.wellpoint.integration.saf.api.SAFServiceFactory.<init>(SAFServiceFactory.java:39)
    at com.wellpoint.integration.saf.api.SAFServiceFactory.getInstance(SAFServiceFactory.java:54)
    at com.idea.app.service.IdeaValidateServiceImpl.getGroupRecordFromSAF(IdeaValidateServiceImpl.java:168)
    at com.idea.app.service.IdeaValidateServiceImpl.ValidateGroupInfo(IdeaValidateServiceImpl.java:87)
    at com.idea.app.validators.GroupNumberValidator.isValidGroup(GroupNumberValidator.java:185)
    at com.idea.app.validators.GroupNumberValidator.validate(GroupNumberValidator.java:97)
    at org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlInputText.validateValue(HtmlInputText.java:52)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1072)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processDecodes(UIInput.java:642)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:209)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$1.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:392)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:238)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processDecodes(AjaxViewRoot.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

The following listing is the axis2.xml:

```
<axisconfig name="AxisJava2.0">
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Parameters -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <parameter name="hotdeployment">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="hotupdate">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="enableSwA">false</parameter>
    <!--Uncomment if you want to enable file caching for attachments -->
    <!--parameter name="cacheAttachments">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="attachmentDIR"></parameter>
    <parameter name="sizeThreshold">4000</parameter-->
    <!--Uncomment if you want to plugin your own attachments lifecycle implementation -->
    <!--<attachmentsLifecycleManager class="org.apache.axiom.attachments.lifecycle.impl.LifecycleManagerImpl"/>-->
    <!--Uncomment if you want to enable the reduction of the in-memory cache of WSDL definitions -->
    <!--In some server environments, the available memory heap is limited and can fill up under load -->
    <!--Since in-memory copies of WSDL definitions can be large, some steps can be taken-->
    <!--to reduce the memory needed for the cached WSDL definitions. -->
    <!--parameter name="reduceWSDLMemoryCache">true</parameter-->
    <!--This will give out the timout of the configuration contexts, in milliseconds-->
    <parameter name="ConfigContextTimeoutInterval">30000</parameter>
    <!--During a fault, stack trace can be sent with the fault message. The following flag will control -->
    <!--that behavior.-->
    <parameter name="sendStacktraceDetailsWithFaults">false</parameter>
    <!--If there aren't any information available to find out the fault reason, we set the message of the exception-->
    <!--as the faultreason/Reason. But when a fault is thrown from a service or some where, it will be -->
    <!--wrapped by different levels. Due to this the initial exception message can be lost. If this flag-->
    <!--is set, then Axis2 tries to get the first exception and set its message as the faultreason/Reason.-->
    <parameter name="DrillDownToRootCauseForFaultReason">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="userName">admin</parameter>
    <parameter name="password">axis2</parameter>
    <!--To override repository/services you need to uncomment following parameter and value SHOULD be absolute file path.-->
    <!--ServicesDirectory only works on the following cases-->
    <!---File based configurator and in that case the value should be a file URL (http:// not allowed)-->
    <!---When creating URL Based configurator with URL file:// -->
    <!--- War based configurator with expanded case , -->
    <!--All the other scenarios it will be ignored.-->
    <!--<parameter name="ServicesDirectory">service</parameter>-->
    <!--To override repository/modules you need to uncomment following parameter and value SHOULD be absolute file path-->
    <!--<parameter name="ModulesDirectory">modules</parameter>-->
    <!--Following params will set the proper context paths for invocations. All the endpoints will have a commons context-->
    <!--root which can configured using the following contextRoot parameter-->
    <!--<parameter name="contextRoot">axis2</parameter>-->
    <!--Our HTTP endpoints can handle both REST and SOAP. Following parameters can be used to distinguiush those endpoints-->
    <!--In case of a servlet, if you change this you have to manually change the settings of your servlet container to map this -->
    <!--context path to proper Axis2 servlets-->
    <!--<parameter name="servicePath">services</parameter>-->
    <!--<parameter name="restPath">rest</parameter>-->
    <!-- Following parameter will completely disable REST handling in Axis2-->
    <parameter name="disableREST" locked="true">false</parameter>
    <!-- Following parameter will suppress generation of SOAP 1.2 bindings in auto-generated WSDL files -->
    <parameter name="disableSOAP12" locked="true">false</parameter>
    <!--POJO deployer , this will alow users to drop .class file and make that into a service-->
    <!--    <deployer extension=".class" directory="pojo" class="org.apache.axis2.deployment.POJODeployer"/>-->
    <!--    <deployer extension=".jar" directory="servicejars" class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer"/>-->
    <!--<deployer extension=".jsa" directory="rmiservices" class="org.apache.axis2.rmi.deploy.RMIServiceDeployer"/>-->
    <!-- Following parameter will set the host name for the epr-->
    <!--<parameter name="hostname" locked="true">myhost.com</parameter>-->
    <!-- If you have a front end host which exposes this webservice using a different public URL  -->
    <!-- use this parameter to override autodetected url -->
    <!--<parameter name="httpFrontendHostUrl">https://someotherhost/context</parameter>-->
    <!--    The way of adding listener to the system-->
    <!--    <listener class="org.apache.axis2.ObserverIMPL">-->
    <!--        <parameter name="RSS_URL">http://127.0.0.1/rss</parameter>-->
    <!--    </listener>-->
    <!-- threadContextMigrators>
        <threadContextMigrator listId="JAXWS-ThreadContextMigrator-List" class="org.apache.axis2.jaxws.addressing.migrator.EndpointContextMapMigrator"/>
    </threadContextMigrators -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Message Receivers -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--This is the deafult MessageReceiver for the system , if you want to have MessageReceivers for -->
    <!--all the other MEP implement it and add the correct entry to here , so that you can refer from-->
    <!--any operation -->
    <!--Note : You can ovrride this for a particular service by adding the same element with your requirement-->
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-out" class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Message Formatter -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--Following content type to message formatter mapping can be used to implement support for different message -->
    <!--format  serialization in Axis2. These message formats are expected to be resolved based on the content type. -->
    <messageFormatters>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
    </messageFormatters>
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Message Builders -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--Following content type to builder mapping can be used to implement support for different message -->
    <!--formats in Axis2. These message formats are expected to be resolved based on the content type. -->
    <messageBuilders>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>
    </messageBuilders>
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Transport Ins -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--    <transportReceiver name="http"-->
    <!--                       class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer">-->
    <!--        <parameter name="port" locked="false">6060</parameter>-->
    <!--If you want to give your own host address for EPR generation-->
    <!--uncommet following paramter , and set as you required.-->
    <!--<parameter name="hostname" locked="false">http://myApp.com/ws</parameter>-->
    <!--    </transportReceiver>-->
    <!--Uncomment if you want to have SMTP transport support-->
    <!--<transportReceiver name="mail" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.SimpleMailListener">-->
    <!--<parameter name="transport.mail.pop3.host" locked="false">127.0.0.1</parameter>-->
    <!--<parameter name="transport.mail.pop3.user" locked="false">axis2</parameter>-->
    <!--<parameter name="transport.mail.pop3.password" locked="false">axis2</parameter>-->
    <!--<parameter name="transport.mail.pop3.port" locked="false">110</parameter>-->
    <!--<parameter name="transport.mail.replyToAddress" locked="false">axis2@127.0.0.1</parameter>-->
    <!--</transportReceiver>-->
    <!--    <transportReceiver name="tcp"-->
    <!--                       class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPServer">-->
    <!--        <parameter name="port" locked="false">6060</parameter>-->
    <!--If you want to give your own host address for EPR generation-->
    <!--uncommet following paramter , and set as you required.-->
    <!--<parameter name="hostname" locked="false">tcp://myApp.com/ws</parameter>-->
    <!--    </transportReceiver>-->
    <!--Uncomment this if you want JMS transport support-->
    <!--    <transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.SimpleJMSListener">-->
    <!--        <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination" locked="false">${filter.jms.queue.response}</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">${filter.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName}</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">${filter.jms.java.naming.factory.initial}</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">${filter.jms.java.naming.provider.url}</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination" locked="false">jms/soap/ResponseQ</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">jms/LocalQCF</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>-->
    <!--        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">file:/</parameter>-->
    <!--    </transportReceiver>-->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Transport Outs -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--    <transportSender name="tcp"-->
    <!--                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportSender"/>-->
    <transportSender name="local" class="com.wellpoint.integration.saf.integration.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender"/>
    <!-- Custom Transport Layer for RPC - AXIS2 Implementation -->
    <!--  transportSender name="rpc"
                     class="com.wellpoint.integration.saf.integration.axis2.transport.rpc.RPCTransportSender"/>-->
    <transportSender name="jms" class="com.wellpoint.integration.saf.integration.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>
    <!--    <transportSender name="jms"-->
    <!--                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>-->
    <transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL" locked="false">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
        <!--        <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding" locked="false">chunked</parameter>-->
    </transportSender>
    <transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL" locked="false">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
        <!--        <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding" locked="false">chunked</parameter>-->
    </transportSender>
    <!-- Uncomment this one with the appropriate papameters to enable the SMTP transport Receiver
   <transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
       <parameter name="transport.mail.smtp.host" locked="false">127.0.0.1</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.mail.smtp.user" locked="false">axis2</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.mail.smtp.password" locked="false">axis2</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.mail.smtp.port" locked="false">25</parameter>
   </transportSender>
   -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Global Modules  -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Comment this to disable Addressing -->
    <!--    <module ref="addressing"/>-->
    <!--    <module ref="logging"/>-->
    <!--    <module ref="soapmonitor"/>-->
    <!--Configuring module , providing parameters for modules whether they refer or not-->
    <!--<moduleConfig name="addressing">-->
    <!--<parameter name="addressingPara" locked="false">N/A</parameter>-->
    <!--</moduleConfig>-->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!-- Phases  -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <phaseOrder type="InFlow">
        <!--  System pre defined phases       -->
        <phase name="Transport">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Transport"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Addressing">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Addressing"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <!--  System pre defined phases       -->
        <!--   After Postdispatch phase module author or or service author can add any phase he want      -->
        <phase name="OperationInPhase"/>
        <phase name="LoggingPhase">
            <handler name="LoggingHandler" class="com.wellpoint.integration.saf.integration.axis2.module.logging.LogHandler"/>
        </phase>
        <!--        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>        -->
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
        <phase name="LoggingPhase">
            <handler name="LoggingHandler" class="com.wellpoint.integration.saf.integration.axis2.module.logging.LogHandler"/>
        </phase>
        <!--        <phase name="soapmonitorPhase"/>        -->
        <!--system predefined phase-->
        <!--these phase will run irrespective of the service-->
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="Security"/>
    </phaseOrder>
    <phaseOrder type="InFaultFlow">
        <phase name="Addressing">
            <handler name="AddressingBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.AddressingBasedDispatcher">
                <order phase="Addressing"/>
            </handler>
        </phase>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="PreDispatch"/>
        <phase name="Dispatch" class="org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase">
            <handler name="RequestURIBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPActionBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPActionBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="RequestURIOperationDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.RequestURIOperationDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.SOAPMessageBodyBasedDispatcher"/>
            <handler name="HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher" class="org.apache.axis2.dispatchers.HTTPLocationBasedDispatcher"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="OperationI
```

Comment: Suggestion: after asking a question, or responding with an answer, look at your post to make sure it's readable.

Comment: I've looked at the revisions and some of the original XML file was truncated...please restore it

Comment: How's that? I reverted to the original, then fixed it again.

Comment: I dont have the files available with me right now....will repost it at the soonest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by versions mismatch of axis2 depenencies like axiom and wsdl. I am not sure specifically which jar it was but it seems older versions were downloaded by maven as part of transitive dependencies of some other artifact. This problem may come up due to other reasons may be but if you get it give a look if the axis2 dependencies(axiom,bcel,wsdl,neethi) are the correct versions of or not.

Hope it helps someone...